# Typhoon won't inject into plain NSObject derived class

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, typhoon

I have a Swift 3 app using Typhoon which successfully injects a NSObject-derived object into a property in several objects deriving from UIViewController. I added code to inject the same object into an object that derives only from NSObject, and the property is always nil upon executing any code in that object.

My assembly looks like this:

```
class CoreComponents: TyphoonAssembly {
dynamic func appInitializer() -> Any {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(AppInitializer.self) {
        (definition) in

        definition!.injectProperty(Selector(("settings")), with: self.provideSettings())
    }
}

dynamic func sideMenu() -> Any {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(SideMenuTableView.self) {
        (definition) in

        definition!.injectProperty(Selector(("settings")), with: self.provideSettings())
    }
}

dynamic func mapViewController() -> Any {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(MapViewController.self) {
        (definition) in

        definition!.injectProperty(Selector(("settings")), with: self.provideSettings())
    }
}

dynamic func provideSettings() -> Any {
    return TyphoonDefinition.withClass(Settings.self) {
        (definition) in
        definition!.scope = TyphoonScope.singleton
    }
}
```

}

In that, only the injection specified by the first method fails to inject. The object it wants to inject into is declared like this:

```
class AppInitializer: NSObject {
    var settings: Settings? // Injected property

    // Other code here
}
```

Does anybody see anything I'm doing wrong?

Here is the relevant portion of a class where the injection works:

```
class SideMenuTableView: UITableViewController {
    var settings: Settings?  // Injected property
    // Other code
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you add a similar to `AppInitializer` code snippet  from an object where it works?

Comment: I tried that, and the same problem happens - the injected property remains nil. My next experiment will be to create hello world from scratch and try the same thing there in case there is some project setting interfering.

Comment: i mean add to the question as code snippet

Comment: Ok, I've edited the original to add that. The only difference I can see is the base class.

Comment: I created a clean app using Xcode and the "single view" template, created an analog for "Settings" and "AppInitializer" and had exactly the same problem.

At that point I gave up, and decided to try the alpha "pure swift" version. That took a little time to get the setup done (the instructions omit the need to create the "Assemblies" and "Typhoon" directory first), but ultimately it worked. All my objects are now able to inject what I need them to.

Comment: can you post your solution as answer? then others can benefit from it (and you can accept your own answer of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this to work, I abandoned the Objective-C compatible version of Typhoon and switched to the "pure swift" version of Typhoon at [their website](https://github.com/appsquickly/TyphoonSwift). The setup is more work, but the code ends up simplified:

```
class CoreComponents: Assembly {
    func provideSettings() -> Definition {
        return Definition(withClass: Settings.self) { d in
            d.setScope(Definition.Scope.Singletone)
        }
    }
}

class AppInitializer: NSObject {
    let settings = CoreComponents.assembly.provideSettings()
    // More code here
}
```

That required instantiating the assembly in my AppDelegate's "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" method with this line:

```
Typhoon.activateAssemblies()
```